# How do I add Wininet .dll and .lib?

Tags: c++, wininet

I previously asked about the following error, wondering why I had it. Turns out its a problem due to my not including/linking the right files.

[image]

That is the error. I have included the header file

```
#include "wininet.h"
```

I dont know how to find or/and add them to my project so I can delete the Download Cache. Does anybody know how I go about adding this as I could not find a solution.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: In your project settings there's a tab (or similar) for linking. There you add the library file (not the DLL).

Comment: I found it, terns out I was just google-ing how to do it wrong :)

Comment: `#pragma comment(lib, "wininet.lib")`